# OpenThread OTBR setup with NetworkManager fails to setup AP; bind9.service fails to run

Tags: networking, border, router, bind9, openthread

I have been using OTBR in docker on a PI3B+, but now I want to have OTBR also act as an AP. I reimaged my PI3B+ according to the directions, following the instructions for setting up AP automatically (e.g. NETWORK_MANAGER == 1), but the no AP setup appears in nmcli. Also, systemctl --failed always shows that bind9.service failed. This was attempted on the latest clean Raspberry PI OS Lite image as well as a PI OS with desktop image.

What could I be missing? In one attempt (running the desktop image) I went ahead and followed the manual AP setup procedure (NETWORK_MANAGER=0), and was able to get the AP to show up, but in that case dnsmasq was failing to run.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just tried on a clean Raspberry PI OS Lite. I saw dnsmasq.service failed, but I did see AP connection listed.

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/ot-br-posix$ nmcli c
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
BorderRouter-AP     02d7cbbf-2f7c-4b11-9666-de64de88ac5d  wifi      wlan0
BorderRouter-Eth    526127e6-5c7d-40c4-baf7-ee6c8f40ab4d  ethernet  eth0
Wired connection 1  16611075-f259-3645-95be-38cf1ca4eee0  ethernet  --
```

And my laptop also detected the new AP. Did `script/bootstrap` succeed?

Also submitted https://github.com/openthread/ot-br-posix/pull/624, could you give it a try?